# d3.geomap is undefined in Grails application

Tags: javascript, html, grails, d3.js

I am using d3.geomap in Grails to create a map of the US.

As said in https://d3-geomap.github.io/ my gsp look like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main" charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'd3.geomap.css')}" type="text/css">
    <g:javascript src="d3.geomap.dependencies.min.js" />
    <g:javascript src="d3.geomap.min.js" />

</head>
<body>

    <script>
        var map = d3.geomap.choropleth()
                .geofile('/topojson/countries/USA.json')
                .projection(d3.geo.albersUsa)
                .column('2012')
                .unitId('fips')
                .scale(1000)
                .legend(true);

        d3.csv("mapusa", function(error, data) {
            d3.select('#map')
                    .datum(data)
                    .call(map.draw, map);
        });
    </script>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The css file d3.geomap.css is under web-app/css.

The js files d3.geomap.dependencies.min.js and d3.geomap.min.js are under web-app/js.

Under grails-app/views/ I have the topojson folder.

When I run the page it gives me:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'choropleth' of undefined
>
> d3.geomap is undefined.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my main.gsp I have:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

When I remove this, then d3.geomap has value and show the US map. I am not sure why they enter in conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below, you will get your desired output of world map. Similarly, you can do it for US maps.

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://d3-geomap.github.io//d3-geomap/css/d3.geomap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://d3-geomap.github.io//d3-geomap/vendor/d3.geomap.dependencies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3-geomap.github.io//d3-geomap/js/d3.geomap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
var map = d3.geomap().geofile('https://d3-geomap.github.io//d3-geomap/topojson/world/countries.json');

d3.select('#map')
.call(map.draw, map);
</script>
```